# Function that removes an element from a sequence

Tags: ocaml

I made a function to remove the n-th element from a sequence. Here's the code

```
let rec remove_at i s () =
  if i < 0 then
    invalid_arg "Seq.remove"
  else
    match s () with
    | Nil ->  invalid_arg "Seq.remove_at"
    | Cons(e, s) -> if i = 0 then s () else Cons(e, remove_at (i - 1) s)
```

But when I test for example `remove_at 0 (of_list[])`, it doesn't raise an exception and I don't know why.

Answer (score 4):

Your function `remove_at` expects not two, but three arguments: an integer, a sequence and the unit value `()`.

When you call `remove_at 0 (of_list[])`, it doesn't actually call the function but waits for the last argument `()` before being executed.

So, you want to call `remove_at 0 (of_list[]) ()` to effectively see what happens.